# Write text into file android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to write data from app database to text file, and I tried the following code :

```
       Context context = getApplicationContext();

        File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir("routable"), "test.txt");



        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("open file Exception", ex.getMessage().toString());
            }
        }

        try {
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_APPEND));
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);

            DAO dao = new DAO(getApplicationContext());
            Cursor res = dao.getSalePoints();
            res.moveToFirst();

            while (!res.isAfterLast()) {

                writer.write(res.getString(0) + ", ");
                writer.write(res.getString(1) + ", ");
                writer.write(res.getString(2) + ", ");
                writer.write(res.getString(3) + ", ");

            res.moveToNext();
        }



        writer.close();
        outputStreamWriter.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Writing file Exception", ex.getMessage().toString());
    }
```

the code created file and it's looping throw the data, but not writing on the file.

- I added `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"`
  in the manifest.

Comment: Did you create the directory `routable`?

Comment: @SimonForsberg it's automatically created when calling `file.createNewFile();` I check it and it's existed with the file on it.

Comment: `file.createNewFile();`. Remove that. Its nonsense. It will create a file in external memory. But it should not be done there. It will be done by openFileOutput(). But that creates one in private internal memory. So you have two files now. The first one empty. The second one written to.

Comment: @AhmedAbdElmoniem No, `file.createNewFile` does not create all directories required for it. Have you checked your logs? Also, if you are using `createNewFile` you should check the `boolean` result of it. Although others are correct that there's no use in using that method. You should probably use `file.mkdirs()` though. But remember to check result value.

Comment: @greenapps remove it and not working

Comment: Not working is not a good description. It will not help you further. You should tell what happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
context.openFileOutput(file.getName(),
```

Replace by

```
new FileOutputStream(file,
```